# Failed requests from Azure topic/subscription at random

Tags: node.js, azure, azureservicebus, azure-node-sdk

I am using Azure's service bus (topics/subscriptions specifically) to send messages back and forth. Seemingly at random, when sending a message to the topic, the message seems to be disappearing and no errors are thrown. If I look at the chart in the Azure management portal for the topic, I can see a portion of messages are failing.

2 questions:

1 - Where is documentation on what can cause a request to fail?

2 - How do I log these requests so I can see the error?

Comment: Almost an year!. Did you find the answer?

Comment: @MarkAlanEvans Nope, I never got this issue resolved, although it appears to have something to do with the lock timeout on the request. The workaround for us was to stop using Azure servicebus.

Comment: What was the solution to your problem?

Comment: Is this something you can repro?

Comment: Would be interested to see some code. Were you using the exception handler for the subscription client?